# Why aren't my new levels available for construction?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Today, I received a screen telling me that two new floors are available. But, they are not able to build, and they don't show up in the game at all.  The latest update gave me two residential floors initially, and supposedly more will appear each Monday.

Does anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it?

Comment: I'm having the same experience.

Comment: It was my pleasure.

Comment: Let me know if yours is fixed later on and I will do the same. Cheers.

Comment: If it resolves in any way, post the answer here.  It's the way the site works.

Comment: Same issue here.

Comment: Just got a 'synch' on tds and now there are several levels available to build

Comment: Ditto. Got the similar message about the availability of new floors and now Bongo Sandwiches, Chiss and Talz apartments, Blaster Repair (Imp) and Planetarium (Rec) are available to build. The only thing that puzzles me now is that the 3 limited edition characters still don't look like droid silhouettes.

Answer (score 1):

It appears as if the floors are now available after a brief in-game update.

[image: new levels]

Comment: I can confirm this!